# I cannot access admin after Opencart move to new server

Tags: php, opencart

i get this error anytime i try to access my admin folder in opencart. i recently moved to a new server

Fatal error: Call to a member function calculate() on a non-object in /var/www/xccc/catalog/controller/module/pavproducttabs.php on line 115

this is the content of line 115

```
$price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['price'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
```

Comment: seems you have this module `pavproducttabs` which  cause your problem. You can remove it manually via ftp file by file.

Comment: Have you updated your config files with the new paths? That's usually where things go wrong when moving servers / site locations

Comment: yes i updated my config file and it worked. Thanks alot

Comment: What is the version of your opencart?